# rewriting C/C++ code with clang LibTooling

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-c++-api, libtooling

I am new to clang and need some help to rewrite c and c++ code for a custom coverage tool I am developing.  As I understand it, I think I need to link to clang's [libTooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html#libtooling) to make a stand alone executable to make something like a code rewriter.

LLVM and clang are huge and it is difficult to know where to start.  There are:

- [AST matchers](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html)
- Source to Source tranformations.
- depth first [RecursiveASTVisitor](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html) classes

that all appear to be doing something similar.

So far my best approach to rewriting some simple code was to follow an old tutorial [tutorial](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/08/basic-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang) and this [3 part tutorial - part 1](https://kevinaboos.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/clang-tutorial-part-i-introduction/).

as a simple example, I would like to be able to take some simple C code like the following:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

// example global function
int
foo(int* a, int *b) {
    if (a[0] > 1) {
        b[0] = 2;
    } else if ((a[0] == 1) && (b[0] == 2)) {
        b[0] = 3;
    } else {
        b[1] = -1;
    }

    a[0] = 2;
    switch (a[0]) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        break;
    case 2:
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return 3;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    int a[3] = {0};
    int b[3] = {0};
    return foo(a, b);
}
```

modify it something along the following lines (with the upper case code insertions):

```
#INCLUDE <CUSTOM_MACROS_AND_INLINES>
#include <stdarg.h>

// example global function
int
foo(int* a, int *b) {
    _BREADCRUMB;
    if (_BREADCRUMB(a[0] > 1)) {
        b[0] = 2;
    } else if (_BREADCRUMB(a[0] == 1) && _BREADCRUMB(b[0] == 2)) {
        b[0] = 3;
    } else {
        b[1] = -1;
        _BREADCRUMB;
        return 1;
    }

    a[0] = 2;
    switch (a[0]) {
    case 0:
        _BREADCRUMB
    case 1:
        _BREADCRUMB
        break;
    case 2:
        _BREADCRUMB
        break;

    default:
        _BREADCRUMB
        break;
    }
    _BREADCRUMB;
    return 3;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    _BREADCRUMB;
    int a[3] = {0};
    int b[3] = {0};
    _BREADCRUMB;
    return foo(a, b);
}
```

Using the RecursiveASTVisitor technique, I am finding it difficult to control where I can insert text into the rewritten output.  Specifically trying to insert after the opening parenthesis of a function so I can drop the above breadcrumb strings into the rewritten code.

Comment: You've stated that it is difficult, but haven't asked a specific question.  Also the example desired input and output seem longer than necessary if the immediate goal is just to insert something at the start of a function.  And do you mean the opening *brace* rather than parenthesis?